# How do I connect to RabbitMQ from my ReactJS application?

Tags: reactjs, rabbitmq, stompjs

Im having trouble connecting to a RabbitMQ instance and can not find a good tutorial or guide for doing so. I can connect to a RabbitMQ websocket by

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:15674/ws')
```

But now I don't know how to connect to my cluster with my credentials. I also need to consume messages from a queue like this `/exchange/myExchange/routingKey`. I was able to easily do this in angular application by using `RxStompService` with the following code

```
  rxStompService.configure({
          brokerURL: `ws://localhost:15674/ws`,
          connectHeaders: {
            login: 'guest',
            passcode: 'guest'
          },
          heartbeatIncoming: 0, // Typical value 0 - disabled
          heartbeatOutgoing: 20000, // Typical value 20000 - every 20 seconds
          reconnectDelay: 200,
          debug: (msg: string): void => {
            console.log(new Date(), msg);
          }
        })

  this.exchange = 'myExchange'
  this.routingKey = 'routingKey'
  this.headers ={
    'x-queue-name': 'myQueue',
    'durable': 'true',
    'auto-delete': 'false'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rxStompService.watch(`/exchange/${this.exchange}/${this.routingKey}`, this.headers ).subscribe((message: Message) => {
     this.user = new User(JSON.parse(message.body))
    });
  }
```

How can I do the same but from my react app?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect and subscribe to a queue by using `stompjs`.

```
import Stomp from 'stompjs'


export function connectRabbit(){

let stompClient

    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:15674/ws')

    const headers = {
        'login': 'guest',
        'passcode': 'guest',
        'durable': 'true',
        'auto-delete': 'false'
    }
    stompClient = Stomp.over(ws)

    stompClient.connect(headers , function(frame){
                console.log('Connected')
               const subscription = stompClient.subscribe('/queue/myQueue', function(message){
                   console.log(message)
               })
    })

}
```

Comment: not that the connection is established and subscribed, how do we read the message from the subscribed queue

Comment: @Arun So I am subscribed to the queue named `myQueue`. When a message is sent, it invokes `function(message)`. In this case I am just logging the message. But you can parse this into an object or anything.